# "An expression of one aspect of " vs "one aspect of the expression"

Tags: meaning, differences, word-order

> A): It is an expression of one aspect of her love.
>
> B): It is one aspect of the expression of her love.

My questions:

1. Do A) and B) mean the same?
2. In the case of B), is **one aspect of** a measure term like **spoon** in "one spoon of sugar"?
3. If not, what if **the** in "the expression of her love" is omitted, can we consider **one aspect of** as a measure term then?

This is really confusing me. Could anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) and B) say two completely different things.

**A): It is an expression of one aspect of her love.**

This says she loves him in, let’s say, two ways - intellectually, and physically. These are the two 'aspects' of her love.

If she tells him, for example, that she is stimulated by his intellect and she finds their common interests make them perfect partners, this could be 'an expression of one aspect (the intellectual aspect) of her love'.

She could express the physical aspect in different ways :), but she could also tell him or write him a note about that too.

**It’s about the way she loves him**, not about *how* it is expressed.

**B): It is one aspect of the expression of her love.**

This says that she loves him but she has lots of ways of showing, or expressing, it - through words, buying him gifts, fixing his car....

**It’s about *how* she chooses to express her love at the time**, not about *the way* she loves him.

Answer (score 0):

The former expresses an aspect (a portion of something).

The latter expresses the entire thing (her love), i.e. all of its aspects.